# C++) why const int*& parameter can't take int* argument?

Tags: c++, reference, constants

before writing, I'm not good at english. So maybe there are many awkward sentence.

```
void Func1(const int* _i) {  };
void Func2(const int& _j) {  };
void Func3(const int* (&_k)) {  };
int main() 
{
    int iNum = 1; 
    int* pInt = new int(1); 
    Func1(pInt); // works; 
    Func2(iNum); //works 
    Func3(pInt); // error 
}
```

I use Visual Studio and error message said
"Cannot convert argument 1 from 'int *' to 'const int *&'"

I know it cant convert because of '&'. _i equals pInt so it may change dereference.
But i used const. so i think it will work but const keyword doesnt work.
why const keyword doesnt work unlike other cases? ex)Func1,Func2

Comment: Related, but takes the angle of "how to circumvent", rather than "why": [Cannot convert argument from int * to const int *&](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39345996/)

Comment: *"But i used const."* -- this makes me think that [What is the difference between `const int*`, `const int * const`, and `int const *`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1143262/) might be relevant.

Comment: @JaMiT ty for answer it helped me!

Comment: Consider what could happen if you allowed it: `const int x = 0; void f(const int*& y) { y = &x; } int main() { int* p = nullptr; f(p); *p = 1234; }`. Oops, assigning to a const object.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
Func1(pInt); // works; int* could convert to const int* implicitly
Func2(iNum); //works; int could be bound to const int&
Func3(pInt); // error;
```

`pInt` is a `int*`, when being passed to `Func3` which expects a reference to `const int*`, then it would be converted to `const int*`, which is a temporary and can't be bound to lvalue-reference to non-const like `const int* &` (lvalue-reference to **non-const** pointer to const int).

If you change the parameter type of `Func3` to `int* &`, then no conversion is required, `pInt` could be bound directly. Or change to `const int* const &` (lvalue-reference to **const** pointer to const int) or `const int* &&` (rvalue-reference) which could bind to temporary.

Comment: ty for answering